# Which Jasper-Reports version to use to allow both Dynamic-Jasper and ireport (which uses jasper 4.1.1) to work together?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, dynamic-jasper

I have created a printing service I want to integrate in a couple applications that require printing. All printing is done by the Jasper Reports library - some by using a jdbc data source and jasper templates (generated by iReport) and some by using a table model data source. To allow dynamic printing of `JTables`, I also use DynamicJasper in my service. The problem is as follows: I cannot find the appropriate JasperReports library version such that will work with both DynamicJasper 3.2.1 and iReport generated templates (which work with jasper reports 4.1.1).
What Jasper Reports version can I use to make both the iReport generated `jasper` files and the Dynamic Jasper 3.2.1 work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the [pom.xml for the DynamicJasper v. 3.2.1](http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/ar/com/fdvs/DynamicJasper/3.2.1/), this library contains this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This means that DJ 3.2.1 supports (official support) JasperReports 3.x version.

The new version of DJ API [will support JR 4.1+](http://dynamicjasper.com/2012/03/14/comming-soon-road-map/).

For more info you can read this two posts on [DJ](http://dynamicjasper.com/forum) support forum: [Won't work with JasperReports 4.1.1 - ID: 3394896](http://dynamicjasper.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=13585) & [JasperReports version](http://dynamicjasper.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=14115).